# "Unrecognized auth response" for every heat stack-create request

Tags: yaml, openstack, openstack-heat

I was trying to learn Heat Orchestration Templates and using [Openstack Template Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/index.html) I tried to make a very simple YAML template similar to the one [provided here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/hot_guide.html#writing-a-hello-world-hot-template).

But the problem is every time I try to run:

```
 heat stack-create -f new.yaml mystack
```

I end up with this error:

```
 INFO heat.engine.stack [-] Stack CREATE FAILED (mystack): Resource CREATE failed: NotImplementedError: Unrecognized auth response
```

or simply `Unrecognized auth response`

I've tried to google this error, but no expected match. :( 
Is there someone who has faced the same problem and resolved it? If yes, do provide the solution. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you able to use the most basic services? For example, "keystone user-list", or "nova boot ..."? Also, please add your openrc file.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel for your comment. A few hours later I realized that I was using Heat's Icehouse setup on Openstack's Havana version. Maybe that's a problem (idk)?? And yes, basic services like "heat stack-list" and  "keystone user-list" were working fine.